# How to set today date as a default date in antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to set today date as a default selected date in ant design date picker.
how can I do that?

```
<DatePicker
 onChange={this.onChange}
 defaultValue={moment("YYYY-MM-DD")}
 />
```

I am trying to do that using this line it is not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just call `moment` without arguments and separate the format to its property.

```
const dateFormat = 'YYYY/MM/DD';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <DatePicker defaultValue={moment()} format={dateFormat} />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container'),
);
```

[image: Edit Q-59518823-DatePicker]

Comment: hello @Dennis Vash, thanks for your response. your answer is right but what if I want to this same thing when I use datepicker in a antd form component?

that time this solution is not working.

Comment: working with form component is entirely different question then what you asked, you should ask another one with specific context

Comment: sorry for that, I just want to know possible solution if you know the answer then please tell me.

Comment: read form docs the answer is there, or ask specific question according to how stack overflow works and Ill answer

Answer (score 0):

you can set a function on mounted to create today's date

```
data() {
  return {
    date: ''
  };
},
methods: {
  getDate() {
    const d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    this.date = [year, month, day].join('-');
  },
},
mounted() {
  this.getDate();
}
```

then you can pass this.date value into the default value like this:

```
<DatePicker
 onChange={this.onChange}
 defaultValue={moment(date)}
 />
```

if this script not working : 
`[year, month, day].join('-')` you can change to `${year}-${month}-${day}`

tell me if this still not work for your problem because from what i'm understand, you are tried to set the default value by today date right?